# VM availibilty report in azure

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Azure availability report is based on the number of heartbeat alert generated in log analytics workspace. Therefore, low availability in the report doesn't really mean that a VM was unavailable due to issues in a given month. It could be different reasons eg. was switched off/deallocated or only created in the last few days in a given month etc.

any logic to improve this any KQL or new azure solution.

Answer (score -1):

- Have you gone through looking for [VM insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-overview), does that provide you the information you required?

> VM insights can help deliver predictable performance and availability of vital applications by identifying performance bottlenecks and network issues and can also help you understand whether an issue is related to other dependencies.

[image]

- You can create a [dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards) with different possible options of [kusto queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query#performing-a-query-across-multiple-resources) that depend on what you are looking for.

Here are the few other examples of Kusto Query
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/examples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/solution-agenthealth#sample-log-searches

- You can even have these additional readings of all possible ways of the information you required.

1. [Visualizing data from Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualizations)
2. [Monitoring Azure virtual machines with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/monitor-vm-azure)
3. [Create and share dashboards of Log Analytics data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/tutorial-logs-dashboards)
4. [Quickstart: Monitor an Azure virtual machine with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/quick-monitor-azure-vm)
5. [Collect data from an Azure virtual machine with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/quick-collect-azurevm)
6. [Overview of VM insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-overview)